# 'album' is not defined at defaultValues, useForm()

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I would like to make a form using useForm() from react-hook-form. I set up a defaultValues section but it tells me 'album is not defined' Here is what I have so far:

```
export function AlbumForm(props) {
   const {register, handleSubmit, errors, control} = useForm({
    defaultValues: album  /////error
        ? album    ///error
        : {
            name: "",
            artist: "",
            imageUrl: "",
        },
    }); 

    const onSubmit =  (data) => {
        console.log(data)
    }
  

    return (
        <div className="AlbumForm">
            <h2>Album Form</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <input type="text" {...register("name")} placeholder="Name" name="name"/>
                <input type="text" {...register("artist")} placeholder="Artist" name="artist" />
                <input type="text" {...register("imageUrl")} placeholder="ImageUrl" name="imageUrl"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: The error message you get is right, you never declare/initialize `album`. What's its value?

Comment: I think it should contain json of a fetched api. I guess I have to do props.album? To fill this variable from a different component

Comment: If you pass it to this component through props, yes you need `props.album`